# How can I connect gltestsrc and vp8enc with Gstreamer?

Tags: opengl, gstreamer

I would like to draw GL scene and broadcast it with tcpserversink with the code below.

```
    gst-launch-1.0 -v gltestsrc ! vp8enc ! webmmux ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=8081
```

I haven't made GL related code, but I believe I can use broadcast gltestsrc just for testing my stream pipeline.

But, In my code, `gltestsrc` and `vp8enc` seems can't be connected. Are there any converter to connect them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer data from `gltestsrc` lives in the OpenGL texture space. You will need to download it to the host memory in order to feed it to the encoder. Also you will most likely need to convert the buffer to a format the video encoder accepts.

Try something like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v gltestsrc ! glcolorconvert ! gldownload ! vp8enc ! webmmux ! ..
```